# Iterating list with datatable in jsf using pagination

Tags: java, mysql, jsf-2, pagination

I have a table name `employee` in mysql ,having around 5-10 lac of data in `employee`. when I am displaying them in data table using `JSF`. I am loading all the records in `ArrayList` and displaying them using `data table` but while list is loading first it is taking time. I am showing 1000 records per page and using pagination displaying other 1000. so what I need to so it doesn't take time in loading at first time to `Arraylist`.Should fetch query on each pagination event?.Any other way of doing it, so my application don't hang kindly suggest me the way.

thank u in advance

Comment: You can use DataModel (for datatable) and inside it you can implement fetch mechanism

Comment: passing id of the 1000th records and getting the next 1000 records by executing query, but the in this case if somebody has deleted some ids so it won't get all the 1000 records. would it good approach to do it?

Comment: We have implemented fetch mechanism, but in our case pagination step is 20 items. It works with very big tables (2 million new transactions every day).